# Jquery add css property if condition is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am stuck on my development which users that clicks the view/hide button and submit the form.

The element with the closest sibling should insert a "display: none"

I have tried adding parent > siblings but it always add the css property on all `div` with `panel-body` class

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btnCreate', function() {

  var subject = $('#txtSubject').val();
  $(".panel").contents().unwrap();
  $(".panel-heading").css("display", "none");
  $(".payslip-label").css("display", "block");

  if ($("i", "button.close").hasClass("fa-eye-slash") == true) {

    $("button.close").parent().siblings().css("display", "none");

  }

  var body = $('#templateBody').html();

  $.ajax({
    url: myRoot + 'Template/AddTemplate',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
      htmlBody: body,
      txtSubject: subject
    }),
    beforeSend: function(e) {
      $('#overlay').show();
      $('#btnCreate').attr("disabled", "disabled");
      $('#btnCancel').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    },
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
      $('#overlay').hide();

      console.log(data);

      location.reload();
    },
    error: function(err) {
      $('#overlay').hide();
      $('#btnSave').removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
      $('#btnCancel').removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12" id="templateBody">
  <ul id="draggablePanelList" class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="panel panel-info">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-value="0" style="font-size: 18px;"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> Payroll Information
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="payslip-label" style="position: relative; min-height: 1px; padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px; display: none;">
          <div style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-weight: 600; color: #5da0cd; text-transform: uppercase;">
            Payroll Information
            <div style="margin: 5px auto 20px auto; border-bottom: 2px solid #5DA0CD; display: block; width: 100%;"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both; content: ' '; display: table;"></div>
        <div style="position: relative; min-height: 1px; padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px;">
          <table border="0" width="100%" style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;"><strong>Pay Period:</strong></td>
                <td style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;">{pay_period}</td>
                <td style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;"><strong>Account No:</strong></td>
                <td style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;">{account_no}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;"><strong>Pay Type:</strong></td>
                <td style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;">{pay_type}</td>
                <td style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;"><strong>Absent:</strong></td>
                <td style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;">{absent}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;"><strong>Rate:</strong></td>
                <td style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;">{rate}</td>
                <td style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;"><strong>Leave:</strong></td>
                <td style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;">{leave}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div style="position: relative; min-height: 1px; padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px;"></div>
        <div style="clear: both; content: ' '; display: table;"></div>
        <div style="display: block; height: 20px;"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="panel panel-info">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-value="1" style="font-size: 18px;"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> Employee Consent
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body" style="position: relative; min-height: 1px; padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px; text-align: center;">
        <p style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">I acknowledge to have received from {Company_name} the amount stated below and have no further claims for services rendered.</p>
        <input type="text" class="signature" style="width: 30%;" />
        <br /> {Lastname}, {firstname}
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="panel panel-info">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-value="0" style="font-size: 18px;"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> Employee Information
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="payslip-label" style="position relative; min-height: 1px; padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px; display: none;">
          <div style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-weight: 600; color: #5da0cd; text-transform: uppercase;">
            Employee Information
            <div style="margin: 5px auto 20px auto; border-bottom: 2px solid #5DA0CD; display: block; top: 50%; width: 100%;"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both; content: ' '; display: table;"></div>
        <div style="position: relative; min-height: 1px; padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px;">
          <table border="0" width="100%" style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;"><strong>Employee Number:</strong></td>
                <td style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;">{employee_number}</td>
                <td style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;"><strong>Date Hired:</strong></td>
                <td style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;">{date_hired}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;"><strong>Employee Name:</strong></td>
                <td style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;">{employee_name}</td>
                <td style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;"><strong>SSS ID:</strong></td>
                <td style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;">{sss_id}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;"><strong>Department Name:</strong></td>
                <td style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;">{department_name}</td>
                <td style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;"><strong>Pagibig ID:</strong></td>
                <td style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;">{pagibig_id}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;"><strong>Tax Code:</strong></td>
                <td style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;">{tax_code}</td>
                <td style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;"><strong>TIN:</strong></td>
                <td style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;">{tin}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

        </div>
        <div style="clear: both; content: ' '; display: table;"></div>
        <div style="position: relative; min-height: 1px; padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px;"></div>
        <div style="clear: both; content: ' '; display: table;"></div>
        <div style="display: block; height: 10px;"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

on the if condition i am stuck on how to add a css property on the closest `panel-body` of the clicked show/hide button.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("button.close").closest("panel").find(".panel-body").hide();
```

Closest() walks back up the DOM tree to find the first element with that selector. Find then walks back down the DOM tree finding all elements with that selector. Hide() does what is says on the tin!

Comment: hi! thanks for responding. unfortunately it doesnt hide the panel-body

Answer (score 0):

what about using the addClass and removeClass jquery functions?

https://api.jquery.com/addclass/
https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

You just define a new CSS class with display: none; Then addClass on your whatever you want to hide and remove the actual one on click on the button.